# 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

I have a Vue application and there is a table where every row has its own id. Then I need to show/hide some elements according condition in v-model directive which compare row id with value in model. The code looks like

```
<b-loading v-model="actionLoading === table.row.id"></b-loading>
```

But this code throws me an error:

> 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS

Can somebody tell me please how to solve this problem? Every row has its own condition based on row id.

Thanks for help.

Comment: For show / hide data we usually use `v-if`, you use `v-model` totally wrong. Its not mention for statements

Comment: which UI library are you using?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Buefy. Its b-loading component. I am not sure if it works with v-if.

Comment: @bill.gates hope it will work with v-if. I will try it tomorov. Thanks.

Comment: @bill.gates v-if does not work.

Comment: You're using it wrong. V-model needs a reactive parameter defined in `data`, asumming you're using Vue 2. What you have there is a condition that will return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `active` prop instead of `v-model`

```js
<b-loading :active="actionLoading === table.row.id"></b-loading>
```

Answer (score 0):

The vue directive for hide/show is `v-show`. This should work perfectly in your case:

```html
<b-loading v-show="actionLoading === table.row.id"></b-loading>
```

`v-model` is typically used for collecting input from user. E.g.

```html
<input type="text" for="rowToLoad" v-model="actionLoading"></input>
```

The above will give an effect that any update user make to the text input will be stored as `actionLoading`. The effect is like calling: `actionLoading = value;` somewhere. That's why it says the expression in `v-model` needs to be used in LHS (of value assignment). It is a 2-way binding that it will also reflect any update to `actionLoading` as the value of the input element.